# How do I add input validation and multiple error messages to sign up form?

Tags: reactjs

I have one input validation implemented for the username, if the username already exists the error is put on the page. I would like to implement more input validations but I'm not sure how.
I want to validate that:

- no fields can be left blank, and that
- the password is not numbers (i.e. 1234 is not valid, the password has to be just alphabet characters like "password")

Here is my page:

```
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useState } from 'react'

const SignUp = ({ onSignup }) => {
let history = useHistory()
const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState('')
const [last_name, setLastName] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [admin, setAdmin] = useState(true)
const [error, setError] = useState(false)


const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    // username already in use
    if(!username) {
        
        return
    }

    onSignup({ first_name, last_name, email, username, password, admin })
        .then(() => {
            history.push('/dashboard')
        }).catch((err) => {
            setError(true)
            setUsername('')
            setPassword('')
            setFirstName('')
            setLastName('')
            setEmail('')
            setAdmin(true)
        })     
}

return (
    <div className='generalFormat'>
        <div className='row justify-content-center'>
            <div className='col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                </div>
                <div className='row'>
                    <form className='signupForm' onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    {error && <p className='signupError'>This username is not available</p>}
                        <div>
                        <input 
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='username'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={username}
                                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input 
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='password'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={password}
                                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <input 
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='first name'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={first_name}
                                onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <input 
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='last name'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={last_name}
                                onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        <input 
                                type='text'
                                placeholder='email'
                                className='form-control'
                                value={email}
                                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        />
                        </div>
                        <div className='d-grid gap-2 mx-auto'>
                            <button className='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                        <Link to="/login">Already have an acount? Log In</Link>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default SignUp

[Here is a image of the error on the username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CoCa.png)